# What is the purpose of Tooltip section in the Visualization pane?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-tooltips?tabs=powerbi-desktop#configure-your-tooltip-report-page

I am experimenting with creating a tooltip page by following the above article for a categorical value column. It is working fine.

However, it continues working even if I remove the categorical column from the Visualization pane's Tooltip section.

So I want to ask - What is the purpose of Tooltip section in the Visualization pane?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the field(s) used in that **Drag tooltip fields here** section is for the default setting of every visual on your source pages (that shows Tooltips properties).

By default on each visual (e.g. a table), if the **Tooltips** property section is turned on, a default setting is **Page = Auto**.  In that scenario, Power BI uses the fields loaded into the **Drag tooltip fields here** section for every Tooltip page, to find candidate tooltip pages to show.

For your scenario to be still working, you must have specified the **Tooltip / Page** on your source visual.

FWIW I prefer to make those specifications on each source visual, to be explicit about what tooltip they should show.  To leave **Page = Auto** invites any future Tooltip page to start appearing as an option, which might confuse the audience.

Comment: TIL! Strange bit of functionality and as you say, it is much better to be explicit.